# How change in discrete bits is equivalent to sinusoidal function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, trigonometry, binary

I am reading this [blog](https://kazemnejad.com/blog/transformer_architecture_positional_encoding/#the-intuition) about positional encoding.

I came across an interesting comparison where the continuous representation of bit change is a sinusoidal function.

See the following bit change:

```
0 ->  0 0  0  0
1 ->  0 0  0  1
2 ->  0 0  1  0
3 ->  0 0  1  1
4 ->  0 1  0  0
5 ->  0 1  0  1
```

> You can spot the rate of change between different bits. The LSB bit is
>   alternating on every number, the second-lowest bit is rotating on
>   every two numbers, and so on.
>
> But using binary values would be a waste of space in the world of
>   floats. So instead, we can use their float continuous counterparts -
>   Sinusoidal functions. Indeed, they are the equivalent to alternating
>   bits. Moreover, By decreasing their frequencies, we can go from LSB
>   bits to MSB